# Why is the command "find | grep 'filename'" so much slower than " find 'filename' "?

Tags: command-line, grep, find, search, file-search

I tried both commands and the command  `find | grep 'filename'`  is many many times slower than the simple `find 'filename'`  command.

What would be a proper explanation for this behavior?

Comment: You are listing every file with find and then passing the data to grep to process. With find used on it's own you are missing the step of passing every listed file to grep to parse the output. This will therefore be quicker.

Comment: Slower in what sense? Does the commands take a different amount of time to complete?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes it takes much longer to complete.

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally. If anything, `time find "$HOME" -name '.profile'` reports a longer time than `time find "$HOME" | grep -F '.profile'`.  (17s vs. 12s).

Comment: @Kusalananda Are you sure it is not a caching issue that is causing this behavior? Which command did you execute first? Also, for me the command find " $HOME | grep -F '.profile' " found much more results than "find "$HOME" -name '.profile' "

Comment: @Kusalananda If you repeat the search more times the latter results will be faster.

Comment: @JenniferAnderson I ran both repeatedly. The 17 and 12 seconds are averages. And yes, the `grep` variation will match anywhere in the `find` result, whereas matching with `find -name` would only match exactly (in this case).

Comment: enclose your code samples within backticks... and add exact command used, haven't seen `find 'filename'` syntax used before.. some experiment made seems that it searches only current directory not subdirectories, while `find | grep` will have to traverse through all files in current and subdirectories recursively

Comment: Yes, `find filename` _would be fast_. I kinda assumed that this was a typo and that the OP meant `find -name filename`.  With `find filename`, only `filename` would be examined (and nothing else).

Comment: @Kusalananda but what does the -name option do?

Comment: The `-name` option instructs `find` to return all files it finds which match the provided name. e.g., `find . -name TODO` would give you all files named `TODO` in the current directory or any of its subdirectories.

Comment: @DaveSherohman But isn't this exactly what the `file` command does without the `-name` option?

Comment: @JenniferAnderson No, see my updated answer.

Comment: @JenniferAnderson - Nope. `find filename` looks at the one specific directory entry `filename` (recursing into it if it's a directory) and returns every file it finds. `find . -name filename` looks at the current directory (recursing into subdirectories) and returns only files named `filename`. Compare `find /etc` vs. `find /etc -name passwd` to see the difference. (And note that, if you're only looking for one specific file at one specific path, using `find` at all is overkill. `ls` will do the job just as well, and likely with less overhead.)

Answer (score 11):

(I'm assuming GNU `find` here)

Using just

```
find filename
```

*would* be quick, because it would just return `filename`, or the names inside `filename` if it's a directory, or an error if that name did not exist in the current directory. It's a very quick operation, similar to `ls filename` (but recursive if `filename` is a directory).

In contrast,

```
find | grep filename
```

would allow `find` to generate a list of *all* names from the current directory and below, which `grep` would then filter. This would obviously be a much slower operation.

I'm assuming that what was *actually* intended was

```
find . -type f -name 'filename'
```

This would look for `filename` as the name of a regular file anywhere in the current directory or below.

This will be as quick (or comparably quick) as `find | grep filename`, but the `grep` solution would match `filename` against the full path of each found name, similarly to what `-path '*filename*'` would do with `find`.

---

The confusion comes from a misunderstanding of how `find` works.

The utility takes a number of *paths* and returns all names beneath these paths.

You may then *restrict* the returned names using various tests that may act on the filename, the path, the timestamp, the file size, the file type, etc.

When you say

```
find a b c
```

you ask `find` to list every name available under the three paths `a`, `b` and `c`.  If these happens to be names of regular files in the current directory, then these will be returned.  If any of them happens to be the name of a directory, then it will be returned along with all further names inside that directory.

When I do

```
find . -type f -name 'filename'
```

This generates a list of all names in the current directory (`.`) and below. Then it restricts the names to those of regular files, i.e. not directories etc.,  with `-type f`.  Then there is a further restriction to names that matches `filename` using `-name 'filename'`.  The string `filename` may be a filename globbing pattern, such as `*.txt` (just remember to quote it!).

Example:

The following seems to "find" the file called `.profile` in my home directory:

```
$ pwd
/home/kk
$ find .profile
.profile
```

But in fact, it just returns all names at the path `.profile` (there is only one name, and that is of this file).

Then I `cd` up one level and try again:

```
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/home
$ find .profile
find: .profile: No such file or directory
```

The `find` command can now not find any path called `.profile`.

However, if I get it to look at the current directory, and then *restrict the returned names to only `.profile`*, it finds it from there as well:

```
$ pwd
/home
$ find . -name '.profile'
./kk/.profile
```

Comment: `find filename` would return only `filename` if `filename` was not of type _directory_ (or was of type directory, but did not have any entry itself)

Answer (score 2):

Non-Technical explanation: Looking for Jack in a crowd is faster than looking for everyone in a crowd and eliminating all from consideration except Jack.

Comment: The problem is that the OP is expecting Jack to be the only person in the crowd. If it is, they're lucky.  `find jack` will list `jack` if it's a file called `jack`, or all names in the directory if it's a directory.  It's a misunderstanding of how `find` works.

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood the problem yet but can provide some more insights.

Like for Kusalananda the `find | grep` call is clearly faster on my system which does not make much sense. At first I assumed some kind of buffering problem; that writing to the console slows down the time to the next syscall for reading the next file name. Writing to a pipe is very fast: about 40MiB/s even for 32-byte writes (on my rather slow system; 300 MiB/s for a block size of 1MiB). Thus I assumed that `find` can read from the file system faster when writing to a pipe (or file) so that the two operations reading file paths and writing to the console could run in parallel (which `find` as a single thread process cannot do on its own.

**It's `find`'s fault**

Comparing the two calls

```
:> time find "$HOME"/ -name '*.txt' >/dev/null

real    0m0.965s
user    0m0.532s
sys     0m0.423s
```

and

```
:> time find "$HOME"/ >/dev/null

real    0m0.653s
user    0m0.242s
sys     0m0.405s
```

shows that `find` does something incredibly stupid (whatever that may be). It just turns out to be quite incompetent at executing `-name '*.txt'`.

**Might depend on the input / output ratio**

You might think that `find -name` wins if there is very little to write. But ist just gets more embarrassing for `find`. It loses even if there is nothing to write at all against 200K files (13M of pipe data) for `grep`:

```
time find /usr -name lwevhewoivhol
```

**`find` can be as fast as `grep`, though**

It turns out that `find`'s stupidity with `name` does not extend to other tests. Use a regex instead and the problem is gone:

```
:> time find "$HOME"/ -regex '\.txt$' >/dev/null     

real    0m0.679s
user    0m0.264s
sys     0m0.410s
```

I guess this can be considered a bug. Anyone willing to file a bug report? My version is find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0

Comment: How repeatable are your timings? If you did the `-name` test first, then it may have been slower due to the directory contents not being cached. (When testing `-name` and `-regex` I find they take roughly the same time, at least once the cache effect has been taken into consideration. Of course it may just be a different version of `find`...)

Comment: @psmears Of course, I have done these tests several times. The caching problem has been mentioned even in the comments to the question before the first answer. My `find` version is find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0

Comment: Why is it surprising that adding `-name '*.txt'` slows down `find`? It has to do extra work, testing each filename.

Comment: @Barmar One the one hand this extra work can be done extremely fast. On the other hand this extra work saves other work. `find` has to write less data. And writing to a pipe is a much slower operation.

Comment: Writing to a disk is very slow, writing to a pipe is not so bad, it just copies to a kernel buffer. Notice that in your first test, writing more to `/dev/null` somehow used *less* system time.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice**: I'll assume that you mean `find . -name filename` (otherwise, you're looking for different things; `find filename` actually looks into a path called *filename*, which might contain almost no files, hence exiting really quickly).

---

Suppose you have a directory holding five thousand files. On most filesystems, these files are actually stored in a [*tree* structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTree), which allows to quickly locate any one given file.

So when you ask `find` to locate a file whose name only requires checking, `find` will *ask* for *that* file, and that file only, to the underlying filesystem, which will read very few pages from the mass storage. So if the filesystem is worth its salt, this operation will run much faster than **traversing the whole tree** to retrieve all entries.

When you ask for plain `find` however that's exactly what you do, you traverse the whole tree, reading. Every. Single. Entry. With large directories, this might be a problem (it's exactly the reason why several softwares, needing to store lots of files on disk, will create "directory trees" two or three components deep: this way, every single leaf only needs to hold fewer files).

Answer (score -2):

Lets assume the file /john/paul/george/ringo/beatles exists and the file you are searching for is called 'stones'

```
find / stones
```

find will compare 'beatles' to 'stones' and drop it when the 's' and 'b' don't match.

```
find / | grep stones
```

In this case find will pass '/john/paul/george/ringo/beatles' to grep and grep will have to work its way through the entire path before determining if its a match.

grep is therefore doing far more work which is why it takes longer

Comment: Have you given that a try?

Comment: The cost of the string comparisons (extremely simple and cheap) is completely dwarfed by the IO (or just syscall if cached) cost of the directory lookups .

Comment: grep isn't a string comparison, its regular expression comparison which means it has to work its way through  the entire string until it either finds a match or reaches the end.  The directory lookups are the same no matter what.

Comment: @Paranoid Hm, what version of _find_ are you talking about? It's apparently not anything like the _find_ I'm used to in debian.